# NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile cause crash

Tags: iphone

I try to use codes

```
-(bool)checIfWorksOnJailbreak;
{

    NSString *s = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Info.plist"];

    NSLog(@"%@",s);

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:s]) {


        NSDictionary *plistDictionary =  (NSDictionary*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:s];


        NSString *valueString = [plistDictionary objectForKey:@"SigerIdentity"];
        if([valueString isEqualToString:@"Apple OS Application Signing"])
            return true;
        else
            return false; 
    }

    return false;

}
```

it always cause error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: 
incomprehensible archive version (-1)'
```

at line

```
NSDictionary *plistDictionary =  (NSDictionary*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:s];
```

Welcome any comment

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted? It's a legitimate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSKeyedUnarchiver` (and `NSKeyedArchiver`) are not for encoding and decoding plists. Instead, they are used to serialize and deserialize objects that implement the `NSCoding` protocol. To read your plist data into a dictionary, you instead should use:

```
NSDictionary *plistDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:s];
```